# How to save the scaled image in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

Thanks in advance.
   I used `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)` tranform on an image [image: normal image]
 And i got  the image [image: scale image] like this.

I am displaying that in an imageview.

Now, if i try to access that image and display in another imageview it is displaying normally like first image.

But i want the scaled image to access. Can any one help me how to save and get the scaled image.
Here this `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)` method will not effect on image.

Comment: imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey.png"];
 merge2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);       imageView2.image = imageview.image;

Comment: edit your question and post code there..Not post code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method helps to scale as well as flip the image

```
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:oldImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```